# take ownership of file under C:\Windows

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory

Hey guys im trying to rename the ActionCenter.dll via our softwaredeployment software. In order to do that i have to take ownership of the file. By default its owned by TrustedInstaller

The software runs the scripts as a local user "baraInstLocal". The user seems to be deactivated when an installation is not running.

```
takeown.exe /F "C:\Windows\System32\ActionCenter.dll"
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Windows\System32\ActionCenter.dll"
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("baraInstLocal","FullControl","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\Windows\System32\ActionCenter.dll" $Acl
Rename-Item "C:\Windows\System32\ActionCenter.dll" "C:\Windows\System32\ActionCenter.dll.backup"
```

When i run this i either get permission denied or file not found. Seems to be a problem because it is in the Windows Folder. Running the powershell ad admin didnt help.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is more of an infrastructure administration issue than a programming problem, so [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) would be a better place for this question. As for your problem, I'd recommend using [`takeown.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753024%28v%3dws.11%29) for changing file ownership.

Comment: As u can see above i tried :) Ill try ServerFault thanks